# Managing my web deployment package on IIS inside a production environment

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, iis, deployment, web-deployment

I am working on an asp.net mvc web application. I have prepared a web deployment package from my staging environment as a zip file, then I publish this web deployment package inside IIS on production server and it worked well.

But currently I need to modify a Controller class to fix a bug on production. But I am not sure how I can publish this specific controller file to my production server .I test the fix on staging and i need to deploy on this controller class to my production server. can anyone advice?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to deploy built `*.dll` assembly file rather than source class file. It should be within `\bin` folder.
Usually it's called as `[your-project-name].dll`.